# Is there a verb that means "to act with honor" or "to follow a code"?

Tags: single-word-requests

To add context, I'm creating a skill for a RPG that covers interacting with a organized crime organization in a somewhat ritualized fashion. This is done to avoid giving offense essentially. This ties in to the sociological concept of "face" as any slight against your honor must be remedied, in extreme cases by duel's to the death. The skill allows you to act without giving offense/slighting honor and to personally "save face".

Comment: Truly outdated but maybe appropriate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auctoritas

Comment: There is *diligence*, which is making sure to do a good job. There is also *diplomatic*, which is being tactful when dealing with others.

Answer (score 3):

I would say [discipline](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discipline). The skill could be called discipline, since discipline is

> "the practice of training people to obey rules or a code of behavior" (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discipline)

and if you have discipline you "follow a code", and follow/listen to what others want/say, and you please people.

Answer (score 0):

As a name for a stat, try *[dignity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dignity)*.

> bearing, conduct, or speech indicative of self-respect or appreciation
>   of the formality or gravity of an occasion or situation.

A low roll for this would mean the character tends to act in an undignified manner.

Comment: I think discipline is a good choice, but for an RPG that term is often more useful in other areas, such as specializations

Comment: While I'm trying to use verbs to have a unified feel, this did give me a great idea, to use [conduct](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conduct?s=t) or [acquit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/acquit). It is, afterall, how well you conduct yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Tao**

> 1  a :  the unconditional and unknowable source and guiding principle
>   of all reality as conceived by Taoists
>   b :  the process of nature by which all things change and which is to be followed for a life of harmony
>
> 2 often not capitalized :  the path of virtuous conduct as
>   conceived by Confucians
>
> 3 often not capitalized :  the art or skill of doing something in
>   harmony with the essential nature of the thing the Tao of archery

"Tao." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 18 May 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You requested a verb.  Here's one:

> Do right.

This is related to

> Do right by someone.
>
> [Do right by](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do_right_by): To treat, deal with, or act toward (someone) in a morally just, socially honorable fashion. *I know her new husband is a good man and wants to do right by our family.* (Wiktionary)

You can shorten it:

> My son, I am not long for this world.  Be good.  Do right.  Be a mensch.

There is a noun:

> Doing right.

We could award points for doing right.

---

If you don't need a verb then I would suggest *[**etiquette**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/etiquette)*:

> (American Heritage)  The practices and forms prescribed by social convention or by authority.